# Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Why this parameter is wrong and making it list (that is not making sense ) 
I have this class (using code first)

```
 public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }

    public int ParshaId { get; set; }
    public int? languageID { get; set; }

    public int WriterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parsha Parsha { get; set; }
    public virtual Writer Writer { get; set; }
    public virtual language languages { get; set; }
```

and i'm getting the headline error but changing it to list

```
 public virtual List< language> languages { get; set; }
```

there is no error why is that  ?

Comment: I think your database and your model are out of sync.

Comment: I dont know , as I say if I change It to list Update Database is working with no error, anyway how can I check if it is as you say ?